# Mailchimp api using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having trouble getting the input to subscribe on submit and having it post to a Mailchimp subscription list.

I am using Jquery and Ajax as you can see in the code. I know my api endpoint is good because I tested it on Postman and was able to add a subscriber. However when I run my code locally it does not work.

I also tried to use the embedded code that mailchimp provides and when I would test, it would say that it is sending me an email to confirm addition to the subscribe list. But I never get an email to confirm and it never added to my subscription list. The code doesnt have https: in the links but I did have it in when I tested and did not work.

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//bigbreakbjj.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=06d10966e94997bd9b2564cb2&amp;id=2eb203c03a" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_06d10966e94997bd9b2564cb2_2eb203c03a" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

```js
$("#new-person-form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
  url: "https://bigbreakbjj.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=06d10966e94997bd9b2564cb2&amp;id=2eb203c03a",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   data: {
    "EMAIL": $("#email").val()
   },
   success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert("Subscribed!");
   },
   error: function() {
    alert("Cannot subscribe");
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4><strong>Sign Up Today</strong></h4>
        <form id="new-person-form" action="https://bigbreakbjj.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=06d10966e94997bd9b2564cb2&amp;id=2eb203c03a">
          <h6>First Name</h6>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="first-name" />
          </div>
          <h6>Last Name</h6>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="last-name" />
          </div>
          <h6>Phone Number</h6>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" />
          </div>
          <h6>Email</h6>
          <div>
            <input type="email" id="email" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Are you running into CORS issues?  are there any javascript console messages when it fails?

Comment: post?u=06d1096…&amp;id=2eb203c03a&callback=jQuery3110857…_148090872309…:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <